# How to use a form to make a get request with header information

Tags: javascript, forms, get, header

I have a form that makes the proper request to the endpoint as a get method.

```
var form = document.createElement('form');
with (form) {
    setAttribute("name", "theForm"); // give form a name
    setAttribute("action","PATHTO"); // give form an action
    setAttribute("method", "get"); // give form a method

}
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(form);
document.forms[0].submit();
```

However, I need to set a header that has a key value pair in the request such as

```
ExtraInfo : 28473432894789238473293874329
```

How would I go about doing that using javascript only to manipulate the form.

Comment: It cannot be done - AFAIK. [Ajax setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) can be an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send headers using `FORM`, instead you can achieve that by using `XMLHttpRequest` this way:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "PATHTO");
oReq.setRequestHeader('ExtraInfo', 28473432894789238473293874329);
oReq.send();
```

Comment: I understand that, however im trying to do that in thew context of an iframe to circumvent to the SameOriginPolicy. How would I use this to present the response in the iframe?